# Check checkbox based on database query

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to populate a checkbox in asp C# based on a value of 0 or 1 from my database.

```
 SqlCommand Comm1 = new SqlCommand("Select Active from dbo.SQLInfrastructure WHERE [Instance] LIKE  '" + label1.Text + "%'", connn);
 connn.Open();
 SqlDataReader DR1 = Comm1.ExecuteReader();


 if (Comm1==1)
 {
     this.activeCheckBox.Checked = false;
 }
 else
 {
     this.activeCheckBox.Checked = true;
 }

 connn.Close();
```

I believe I am close, this is on the page_load event. This code does not work but conveys what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: SQL injection attack much?

Comment: Does the query will always return only 1 record?

Comment: if you are using a dataReader you need to loop through it in a while loop `while(DR1.Read()) { }` do a google search on the topic

Comment: `Comm1==1`?  An SqlCommand object is not an integer.

Comment: I would suggest looking at a library to do all the syntactic sugar for you - Dapper is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [SqlDataReader example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx)

Essentially, before you can use the content of the reader you have to *move* it to the first record

Also (further to STLDeveloper's comment)... consider using [parameterised queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of direct values

Comment: I will absolutely use parameterised queries. I wanted to oversimplify it so I could get the code working. Thanks for the comments tho

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCommand Comm1 = new SqlCommand("Select Active from dbo.SQLInfrastructure WHERE [Instance] LIKE  '" + label1.Text + "%'", connn);
connn.Open();
SqlDataReader DR1 = Comm1.ExecuteReader();

this.activeCheckBox.Checked = DR1.Read() && DR.GetBoolean(0);

connn.Close();
```

Also,

This is very much wrong to what you have done over here,

```
if (Comm1==1){}
```

since, the `SqlCommand` object `Comm1` cannot have an integer value in it as said by [LarsTech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/719186/larstech) in the comments.

Comment: How is "The ExecuteNonQuery()returns the number of rows affected by an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement." useful when he's `selecting`?

Comment: Cool... except that _still_ doesn't really help... what if the returned value for `Active` is false?

Comment: The `else` part...??

Comment: You can't just check if there is any record returned... you have to check the value as well (I've edited your code to reflect this)

Answer (score 0):

`DataAdapter` might be an other solution,

```
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("command",connection);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adp.Fill(dt);

if((int)dt.AsEnumerable().First()["Active"] == 1) {
    this.activeCheckBox.Checked = false;
}
else{
    this.activeCheckBox.Checked = true;
}
```

Hope helps,

Comment: I get an access violation when I use this example. Thanks for your input

Comment: I assumed that "Active" has an integer datatype at sql? If there is a missmatch, it is normal to get access violation. @PoopaSaurasRex

Comment: Thank you! it works.Yes the issue was at the database level, I changed it to int.

Comment: Your welcome, (don't forget to upvote if it is the answer :)). @PoopaSaurasRex

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `ExecuteScalar()` method of the `SqlCommand` class:

```
this.activeCheckBox.Checked = (bool)Comm1.ExecuteScalar;
```

Also, as [STLDeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1736047/stldeveloper) indicates, you should really be using [SqlParameters](https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) to pass user input into your SQL statement.